# get the sum of a column in all rows mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a `order` table and I want to get the total sale till now. This table contain the column  `grand_total`. I want to get the sum of this column from all rows.

```
   order_id grand_total 
   1         10
   2         20
```

query should output 30

Thanks

Comment: By the way where I can read the full form of RTFM?

Comment: it means 'read the f*king manual'

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
SELECT SUM(grand_total) FROM order
```

Here is a [reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-functions.html) to aggregate functions in MYSQL.

Comment: @Jim I wasted a few seconds double checking whether or not the question was straight forward :)